# Calling a static method from NSTimer. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, static-methods

Is it allowed to call a static method from an NSTimer? The compiler will not allow this, complaining with the cryptic "Extra argument 'selector' in call.

```
   struct MyStruct {
        static func startTimer() {
            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: MyStruct.self, selector: "doStuff", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

        static func doStuff() {
            println("Doin' it.")
        }
    }

   MyStruct.startTimer()
```

But of course, this works fine...

```
class MyClass {
    func startTimer() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "doStuff", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func doStuff() {
        println("Doin' it.")
    }
}

var instanceOfClass = MyClass()
instanceOfClass.startTimer()
```

Do I just have the syntax wrong, or is it not allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSTimer` utilizes the Objective-C runtime in order to dynamically invoke methods. When declare a `struct`, you are using the Swift runtime, therefore it is not possible for `NSTimer` to cooperate. Structures differ from classes, and you can read more about them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html).

Also, a `static` function is the equivalent of a class method in Objective-C, so if that was your original objective then the following should suffice:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    class func startTimer() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "doStuff", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    class func doStuff() {
        println("Doin' it.")
    }
}

MyClass.startTimer()
```

Comment: I have almost the identical code, and it does not work. In fact, if I paste in this exact code, it does not work. `Unrecognized selector`... Has using `class` worked for anyone?

Comment: @SimplGy: Try prefixing your function with the attribute `@objc`.

Comment: Note: You must inherit from `NSObject` for it to be able to find your class func selector. If you do not, you will get a runtime crash `Unrecognized selector`.